# Jboss Service / Managed Bean Question

Tags: jboss, service, entitymanager, jmx

I have a managed bean / service running inside of JBOSS.  I then have a quartz job that will occasionally wake up and call a method of the managed bean.  This method is sometimes long and drawn out, and since I don't want the quartz job to time out, I have implemented a thread within the managed bean to perform the processing.  When the thread is finished I need to update a database table with the results.  This is a very serial process and it needs to be based upon some business rules, etc.

My main question is that I can use an EntityManager within the service without a problem however I can not use it from within the thread, I get a NullPointerException.  What would be the best way to address this?

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: Do you obtain the EntityManager in the EJB as a @PersistenceContext ?

Comment: Yes I do.  After a bunch of research, I've found that the EntityManager is not threadsafe and therefore can not be used / accessed in child threads.

Answer (score 0):

As creating threads in appservers is discouraged, I'd modify the setup a bit.

I'd move the core of processing to a message driven bean, and have the Quartz job just send a message to the queue on which the MDB is listening.  The MDB in turn can call your EJB, and like this everything remains within what's allowed by the standard.

Comment: This was the original way that I had it set up however the long process would timeout the MDB bean and/or the EJB.  What I eneded up find was a way to annotate the EJB so that it would not timeout.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation and specification the Entity Manager is not thread safe and can not be used across different child threads as I had originally had in mind.  I ended up going back to the original design similar to the one provided by fvu, however I found some annotations that would allow me to modify the been timeout period and allow the long running process to work properly.  Here's the annotation that I used:

```
@PoolClass(value=org.jboss.ejb3.StrictMaxPool.class, timeout=360000000L)
```

Comment: That timeout is 3600 seconds * 1000 milliseconds * 100 HOURS???  That's some long-running bean you have ;-)